# How do we interpret $E=|\vec{p}|c$ in classical electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum

$$E=|\vec{p}|c$$

Can this relation be derived purely from electromagnetic theory?

I.e., is this a general statement about the EM field as whole and not just individual photons?

I.e.

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0}|\vec{E}|^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} |\vec{B}|^2\right) dv \ = \ |\epsilon_{0}\vec{E}×\vec{B}| \ dv(c) $$

The energy within a volume $dv$, is equal to the momentum in volume $dv * c$.

I am fairly confident that this expression is not true.

The closest relation I can get is:

$$\vec{S} = \frac{\vec{p}}{c^2}$$

Which is a relation about the energy FLUX and momentum density, (multiply by c), and it fits the same form, but how would we interpret $\vec{S} c$, where the units are:

$$\frac{J}{ms} \ \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 4):

> The closest relation I can get is

> $\vec{S} = \frac{\vec{p}}{c^2}$

This looks backwards.

We can define the electromagnetic momentum *density* $\vec p$ as:
$$
\vec p \equiv \frac{\vec S}{c^2}\;.
$$

For an electromagnetic plane wave travelling in the $\hat z$ direction, we also have a relationship between the Poynting vector $\vec S$ and the energy density $u$:
$$
\vec S = uc\hat z\;.
$$

Using the above two equations we can write:
$$
u=pc
$$

Comment: Right, but this only works because plane waves follow  $$|\vec{E}| = |\vec{B}| c$$ Which is not true for the EM field in general, only plane waves.

Comment: After more thinking, I think this relation holds for all Em waves, atleast it does for the hertzian dipole[anyone give me a link to prove this as a fact is welcome  maybe jefimenkos equations]. This is probably where I think a distinction must be made between the EM wave component of the  EM field   and the static component. I am unaware of how photons fit into a static EM situation. Which is probably why this relation breaks down when considering the non EM wave component.